# How to know a Database needs compact and repair?

Tags: vb6, ado

As you know in (Windows OS > Disk Defragment) there is a button with name of (Analyze)

Is in (VB6 > ADO) an option like this:

True (the database needs to compact and repair)

False (the database doesn't need compact and repair)

Comment: There isn't an option in ADO for that. Remember ADO covers many database types. Which database type are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already answered elsewhere this question has been crossposted to:

```
Dim Savings As Long

Savings = Conn.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Compact Reclaimed Space Amount").Value
```

This gives you a size in bytes of the estimated savings to be gained by the next compact operation, if we assume we have a Jet MDB open.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. If you have heavy updated database (Access MDB), you could create your own rule. You cannot analyse fragmentation of mdb file, but you can guess need of compression when mdb files groves above a limit (jet core doesn't shrink mdb file without explicit compression). How to guess or compute this limit is hard to say, it depends on your application and data structure.

Comment: Don't make up answers when you don't know.

Comment: @Bob77 This was IMHO my best answer. I have this solution in my commercial program.  I have missed connection properties, how could I..? Its great be taught, it is worth -1, thanks.